# Codes Work In Codepen But Don't Work In My Computer

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slideshow, codepen

Guys recently I have opened a question here: [Why My Javascript Slideshow Doesnt Work Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401859/why-my-javascript-slideshow-doesnt-work-properly/63403133#63403133)

And in code snippet my codes work fine in stackoverflow and codepen but in my computer it doesnt. Can someone please help me? Why it is not working?

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <style>
            .nav{
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;;
                left: 0;
                height:15%;
                top:0px;
                font-size:15px;
                z-index:1000;
            }
            .a{
                position: relative;
                top:70%;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-decoration: none;  
                font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                color:rgb(90, 76, 76);
            }
            .a:hover{
                text-decoration: none;  
                border-bottom: 2px red solid;
                color:rgb(129, 74, 129);
            }
            #aiki{
                margin:3%;
            }
            #auc{
                border-right: 30px solid transparent;
            }
            #adort{
                border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            }
            #abir{
                margin:3%;
            }
            .sag2{
                position: absolute;
                
            }
            .sol{
                position: absolute;
                top:-5%;
                margin-left:70%;
            }
            .as{
                position: relative;
                top:70%;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-decoration: none;  
                font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                margin-left:15%;
                color:white;
            }
            .a:hover{
                text-decoration: none;  
                color:rgb(129, 74, 129);
            }
            .img1{
                background-color: rgb(155, 151, 151);
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 25%;
            }
            @media (max-width: 1000px) {
                .a{
                    display: none;
                }
             }
             #span{
                 color:white;
                 margin: 5%;
             }
             .slider{
             position:relative;
             overflow:hidden;
             height: 100vh;
             width: 100vw;
         }
         .slide{
             position:absolute;
             top:0;
             left:0;
             width: 100%;
             height:100%;
             opacity:0;
             transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
         }
         .slide.current{
             opacity:1;
         }
         .slide.current .content{
             opacity: 1;
             left:0;
            transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0.3s;
         }
         .content{
             position: absolute;
             bottom: 70px;
             left:-600px;
             opacity:0;
             width:600px;
             background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
             color: #333333;
             padding:35px;
         }
         .content h1{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
         }
         #next{
             position:absolute;
             top:200px;
             right:15px;
         }
         #prev{
             position:absolute;
             top:200px;
             left:15px;
         }
         .buttons{
            border: 2px solid #ffffff;
            background-color: transparent;
            color:#ffffff;
            cursor:pointer;
            padding: 13px 15px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            outline: none;
            transition: 1.5s;
         }
         .buttons:hover{
             background-color: white;
             color:black;
             transition: 1.5s;
         }
         @media (max-width: 800px) {
         .slide .content{
            bottom:-300px;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
         }
         .slide.current .content{
             transform: translateY(-300px);
         }
        }
         .slide:first-child{
            background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
         }
         .slide:nth-child(2){
            background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900") ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
         }
         .slide:nth-child(3){
            background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
         }
         .slide:nth-child(4){
            background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
         }
         .slide:nth-child(5){
            background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900") ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
         }
        </style>
        <body>
            <script>
                window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
        
                function scrollFunction() {
                if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.height = "20%";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.marginLeft = "20%";
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.marginLeft = "40%";
                    //document.getElementById("sag2").style.left = "20%";
                    
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.height = "15%";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.marginLeft = "0%";
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.marginLeft = "70%";
                }
                }
                const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
                const next = document.querySelector("#next");
                const prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
                const auto = true;
                const invervalTime = 5000;
                let slideInterval;
    
                function nextslide(){
                    //Get current class
                    const current = document.querySelector('.current');
                    //Remove current class
                    current.classList.remove('current')
                    //Check for next slide
                    if(current.nextElementSibling){
                        //Add current to nextElementSibling
                        current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current');
                    }else{
                        //Add current to start
                        slides[0].classList.add('current');
                    }
                    setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
                }
                
                function prevslide(){
                    //Get current class
                    const current = document.querySelector('.current');
                    //Remove current class
                    current.classList.remove('current')
                    //Check for previous slide
                    if(current.previousElementSibling){
                        //Add current to previousElementSibling
                        current.previousElementSibling.classList.add('current');
                    }else{
                        //Add current to last
                        slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('current')
                    }
                    setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
                }
    
                //button events
                next.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                    nextslide();
                    if(auto){
                    clearInterval(slideInterval)
                    slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                }
                });
                prev.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                    prevslide();
                    if(auto){
                    clearInterval(slideInterval)
                    slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                }
                });
    
                //autoplay
                if(auto){
                    slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                }
             </script>
            <nav class="nav" id="navs">
                <nav class="img1" id="imgg" ><span id="span">0 533 295 42 35</span><span id="span">blabla@gmail.com</span></nav>
                <div class="as">
                <div class="sag" id="sag2">
                <a class="a" id="abir">sad</a>
                <a class="a" id="aiki">sad</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sol" id="sol">
                <a class="a" id="auc">sad</a>
                <a class="a" id="adort">sad</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="slider">
                <div id="firstcontent"class="slide current">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>Slide One</h1>
                        <p>Slide One's paraghrap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>Slide Two</h1>
                        <p>Slide Two's paraghrap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>Slide Third</h1>
                        <p>Slide Third's paraghrap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>Slide Four</h1>
                        <p>Slide Four's paraghrap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>Slide Five</h1>
                        <p>Slide Five's paraghrap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <button class="buttons"id="prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
                <button class="buttons"id="next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check F12 console tab for errors, and Network tab for resources that are failing to load.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript not working from header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147108/javascript-not-working-from-header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I figured it out. By having the javascript ABOVE the html, `querySelector` wasn't seeing your next/prev buttons so the variables that held them were actually set as `null`. Simply moving the javascript to the bottom fixed this for me.

Or wrapping your javascript in `window.onload = function()` also will solve it.

```
    <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <style>
                .nav{
                    width: 100%;
                    position: fixed;;
                    left: 0;
                    height:15%;
                    top:0px;
                    font-size:15px;
                    z-index:1000;
                }
                .a{
                    position: relative;
                    top:70%;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    color:rgb(90, 76, 76);
                }
                .a:hover{
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    border-bottom: 2px red solid;
                    color:rgb(129, 74, 129);
                }
                #aiki{
                    margin:3%;
                }
                #auc{
                    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
                }
                #adort{
                    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                }
                #abir{
                    margin:3%;
                }
                .sag2{
                    position: absolute;
                    
                }
                .sol{
                    position: absolute;
                    top:-5%;
                    margin-left:70%;
                }
                .as{
                    position: relative;
                    top:70%;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    margin-left:15%;
                    color:white;
                }
                .a:hover{
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    color:rgb(129, 74, 129);
                }
                .img1{
                    background-color: rgb(155, 151, 151);
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 25%;
                }
                @media (max-width: 1000px) {
                    .a{
                        display: none;
                    }
                 }
                 #span{
                     color:white;
                     margin: 5%;
                 }
                 .slider{
                 position:relative;
                 overflow:hidden;
                 height: 100vh;
                 width: 100vw;
             }
             .slide{
                 position:absolute;
                 top:0;
                 left:0;
                 width: 100%;
                 height:100%;
                 opacity:0;
                 transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
             }
             .slide.current{
                 opacity:1;
             }
             .slide.current .content{
                 opacity: 1;
                 left:0;
                transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0.3s;
             }
             .content{
                 position: absolute;
                 bottom: 70px;
                 left:-600px;
                 opacity:0;
                 width:600px;
                 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
                 color: #333333;
                 padding:35px;
             }
             .content h1{
                margin-bottom: 10px;
             }
             #next{
                 position:absolute;
                 top:200px;
                 right:15px;
             }
             #prev{
                 position:absolute;
                 top:200px;
                 left:15px;
             }
             .buttons{
                border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                background-color: transparent;
                color:#ffffff;
                cursor:pointer;
                padding: 13px 15px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                outline: none;
                transition: 1.5s;
             }
             .buttons:hover{
                 background-color: white;
                 color:black;
                 transition: 1.5s;
             }
             @media (max-width: 800px) {
             .slide .content{
                bottom:-300px;
                left:0;
                width:100%;
             }
             .slide.current .content{
                 transform: translateY(-300px);
             }
            }
             .slide:first-child{
                background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(2){
                background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(3){
                background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(4){
                background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(5){
                background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
            </style>
</head>
            <body>
                <nav class="nav" id="navs">
                    <nav class="img1" id="imgg" ><span id="span">0 533 295 42 35</span><span id="span">blabla@gmail.com</span></nav>
                    <div class="as">
                    <div class="sag" id="sag2">
                    <a class="a" id="abir">sad</a>
                    <a class="a" id="aiki">sad</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sol" id="sol">
                    <a class="a" id="auc">sad</a>
                    <a class="a" id="adort">sad</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="slider">
                    <div id="firstcontent"class="slide current">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide One</h1>
                            <p>Slide One's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Two</h1>
                            <p>Slide Two's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Third</h1>
                            <p>Slide Third's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Four</h1>
                            <p>Slide Four's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Five</h1>
                            <p>Slide Five's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button class="buttons"id="prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
                    <button class="buttons"id="next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
                            <script>
                    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
            
                    function scrollFunction() {
                    if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
                        document.getElementById("navs").style.transition = "2s";
                        document.getElementById("navs").style.height = "20%";
                        document.getElementById("sag2").style.transition = "2s";
                        document.getElementById("sag2").style.marginLeft = "20%";
                        document.getElementById("navs").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                        document.getElementById("sol").style.transition = "2s";
                        document.getElementById("sol").style.marginLeft = "40%";
                        //document.getElementById("sag2").style.left = "20%";
                        
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("navs").style.height = "15%";
                        document.getElementById("sag2").style.transition = "2s";
                        document.getElementById("sag2").style.marginLeft = "0%";
                        document.getElementById("navs").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                        document.getElementById("sol").style.transition = "2s";
                        document.getElementById("sol").style.marginLeft = "70%";
                    }
                    }
                    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
                    const next = document.querySelector("#next");
                    const prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
                    const auto = true;
                    const invervalTime = 5000;
                    let slideInterval;
        
                    function nextslide(){
                        //Get current class
                        const current = document.querySelector('.current');
                        //Remove current class
                        current.classList.remove('current')
                        //Check for next slide
                        if(current.nextElementSibling){
                            //Add current to nextElementSibling
                            current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current');
                        }else{
                            //Add current to start
                            slides[0].classList.add('current');
                        }
                        setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
                    }
                    
                    function prevslide(){
                        //Get current class
                        const current = document.querySelector('.current');
                        //Remove current class
                        current.classList.remove('current')
                        //Check for previous slide
                        if(current.previousElementSibling){
                            //Add current to previousElementSibling
                            current.previousElementSibling.classList.add('current');
                        }else{
                            //Add current to last
                            slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('current')
                        }
                        setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
                    }
        
                    //button events
                    next.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                        nextslide();
                        if(auto){
                        clearInterval(slideInterval)
                        slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                    }
                    });
                    prev.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                        prevslide();
                        if(auto){
                        clearInterval(slideInterval)
                        slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                    }
                    });
        
                    //autoplay
                    if(auto){
                        slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                    }
                 </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I will try it but can you explain to me that why that it doesnt work when I put top of my body?

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL Click the link in my comment. Short answer: the elements don't exist yet in the DOM, so your Javascript can't parse them.

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL, as disinfor pointed out, when you put the `querySelector`s above the HTML at that point the javascript is looking for those elements in the DOM. However, they haven't been loaded in the DOM just yet, which means as far as the javascript is concerned those elements don't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define script after page load

```
  <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <style>
                .nav{
                    width: 100%;
                    position: fixed;;
                    left: 0;
                    height:15%;
                    top:0px;
                    font-size:15px;
                    z-index:1000;
                }
                .a{
                    position: relative;
                    top:70%;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    color:rgb(90, 76, 76);
                }
                .a:hover{
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    border-bottom: 2px red solid;
                    color:rgb(129, 74, 129);
                }
                #aiki{
                    margin:3%;
                }
                #auc{
                    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
                }
                #adort{
                    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                }
                #abir{
                    margin:3%;
                }
                .sag2{
                    position: absolute;
                    
                }
                .sol{
                    position: absolute;
                    top:-5%;
                    margin-left:70%;
                }
                .as{
                    position: relative;
                    top:70%;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    margin-left:15%;
                    color:white;
                }
                .a:hover{
                    text-decoration: none;  
                    color:rgb(129, 74, 129);
                }
                .img1{
                    background-color: rgb(155, 151, 151);
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 25%;
                }
                @media (max-width: 1000px) {
                    .a{
                        display: none;
                    }
                 }
                 #span{
                     color:white;
                     margin: 5%;
                 }
                 .slider{
                 position:relative;
                 overflow:hidden;
                 height: 100vh;
                 width: 100vw;
             }
             .slide{
                 position:absolute;
                 top:0;
                 left:0;
                 width: 100%;
                 height:100%;
                 opacity:0;
                 transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
             }
             .slide.current{
                 opacity:1;
             }
             .slide.current .content{
                 opacity: 1;
                 left:0;
                transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0.3s;
             }
             .content{
                 position: absolute;
                 bottom: 70px;
                 left:-600px;
                 opacity:0;
                 width:600px;
                 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
                 color: #333333;
                 padding:35px;
             }
             .content h1{
                margin-bottom: 10px;
             }
             #next{
                 position:absolute;
                 top:200px;
                 right:15px;
             }
             #prev{
                 position:absolute;
                 top:200px;
                 left:15px;
             }
             .buttons{
                border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                background-color: transparent;
                color:#ffffff;
                cursor:pointer;
                padding: 13px 15px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                outline: none;
                transition: 1.5s;
             }
             .buttons:hover{
                 background-color: white;
                 color:black;
                 transition: 1.5s;
             }
             @media (max-width: 800px) {
             .slide .content{
                bottom:-300px;
                left:0;
                width:100%;
             }
             .slide.current .content{
                 transform: translateY(-300px);
             }
            }
             .slide:first-child{
                background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(2){
                background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(3){
                background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(4){
                background-image:url("https://www.gladsos.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gladsos-slider-vr.jpg") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
             .slide:nth-child(5){
                background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
             }
            </style>
            <body>
               
                <nav class="nav" id="navs">
                    <nav class="img1" id="imgg" ><span id="span">0 533 295 42 35</span><span id="span">blabla@gmail.com</span></nav>
                    <div class="as">
                    <div class="sag" id="sag2">
                    <a class="a" id="abir">sad</a>
                    <a class="a" id="aiki">sad</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sol" id="sol">
                    <a class="a" id="auc">sad</a>
                    <a class="a" id="adort">sad</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="slider">
                    <div id="firstcontent"class="slide current">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide One</h1>
                            <p>Slide One's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Two</h1>
                            <p>Slide Two's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Third</h1>
                            <p>Slide Third's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Four</h1>
                            <p>Slide Four's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Slide Five</h1>
                            <p>Slide Five's paraghrap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button class="buttons"id="prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
                    <button class="buttons"id="next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
            </body>
            <script>
                window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
        
                function scrollFunction() {
                if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.height = "20%";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.marginLeft = "20%";
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.marginLeft = "40%";
                    //document.getElementById("sag2").style.left = "20%";
                    
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.height = "15%";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sag2").style.marginLeft = "0%";
                    document.getElementById("navs").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.transition = "2s";
                    document.getElementById("sol").style.marginLeft = "70%";
                }
                }
                const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
                const next = document.querySelector("#next");
                const prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
                const auto = true;
                const invervalTime = 5000;
                let slideInterval;
    
                function nextslide(){
                    //Get current class
                    const current = document.querySelector('.current');
                    //Remove current class
                    current.classList.remove('current')
                    //Check for next slide
                    if(current.nextElementSibling){
                        //Add current to nextElementSibling
                        current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current');
                    }else{
                        //Add current to start
                        slides[0].classList.add('current');
                    }
                    setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
                }
                
                function prevslide(){
                    //Get current class
                    const current = document.querySelector('.current');
                    //Remove current class
                    current.classList.remove('current')
                    //Check for previous slide
                    if(current.previousElementSibling){
                        //Add current to previousElementSibling
                        current.previousElementSibling.classList.add('current');
                    }else{
                        //Add current to last
                        slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('current')
                    }
                    setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
                }
    
                //button events
                next.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                    nextslide();
                    if(auto){
                    clearInterval(slideInterval)
                    slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                }
                });
                prev.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                    prevslide();
                    if(auto){
                    clearInterval(slideInterval)
                    slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                }
                });
    
                //autoplay
                if(auto){
                    slideInterval = setInterval(nextslide, invervalTime);
                }
             </script>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Always is Recommend put all the Javascript code Before the `**</body>**` tag in the HTML, 1) The reason behind this is as the Head gets loaded before the body. Any dynamic javascript code that gets executed in the body on load will execute correctly. If you have javascript that is just before the  tag then any javascript calls made to functions by your page as it loads will error.

all the code working

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/ExKPdmj

Comment: You do not *always* need to put Javascript before the closing `</body>` tag. There are valid reasons you shouldn't. You should update your answer to remove `always` and explain _why_ it might be recommended to put your JS at the bottom.

Comment: The sir is happy now?